# Convert Bootstrap 5 to Angular (13+) components

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Angular does not support [optional host-element](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18877) and [containerless components](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28132) so it means every component has its own (`div`) wrapper but for designing Bootstrap components we need a host-less component (without extra `div`) to help Bootstrap find its pre-defined structure. (in some use cases especially internal components like `inputgroup-text` or `carousel-item`)

**An annoying `div` that destroys the internal structure of Bootstrap for internal Angular components.**

[image]
[image]

I want to know do you have a design suggestion to create Angular components like below?

**Bootstrap 5**

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
</div>
```

**Angular components**

```html
<bs-inputgroup class="mb-3">
  <bs-inputgroup-text>$</bs-inputgroup-text>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <bs-inputgroup-text>.00</bs-inputgroup-text>
</bs-inputgroup>
```

Or

**Bootstrap 5**

```html
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Angular components**

```html
<bs-carousel>
  <bs-carousel-item>
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="..." />
  </bs-carousel-item>
  <bs-carousel-item>
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="..." />
  </bs-carousel-item>
  <bs-carousel-item>
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="..." />
  </bs-carousel-item>
</bs-carousel>
```

Is it possible to convert each part of Bootstrap 5 to an Angular component without a containerless/host-less feature?

I don't want to use directives just components so please consider that.

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling angular view-encapsulation and see if that works: https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation

```
  selector: 'app-no-encapsulation',
  template: `
    <h2>None</h2>
    <div class="none-message">No encapsulation</div>
  `,
  styles: ['h2, .none-message { color: red; }'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class NoEncapsulationComponent { }
```

Comment: The Result <app-no-encapsulation _ngcontent-quh-c56=""><h2>None</h2><div class="none-message">No encapsulation</div></app-no-encapsulation>

`app-no-encapsulation` is the annoying host and still there!!!